# Custom dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels appear as percentages on Firefox

Tags: apache, dojo, dijit.form

After adding a custom slider range (1 to 12), like this:

```
<div id="mySlider" > <!-- intialized on javascript -->
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.HorizontalRule" 
     data-dojo-props='container:"bottomDecoration", count:2, style:{height:"5px"}'></div>
<ol data-dojo-type="dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" data-dojo-props='container:"bottomDecoration", style:{height:"1em", fontSize:"75%"}'>
    <li><span style="font-size: small">1</span></li>                                                   
    <li><span style="font-size: small">12</span></li>
</ol>
```

I got percentages (0%, 100%) instead of a custom range.

This happens only on Firefox, for pages which are served by Apache. I tried to run the same page on localhost with Glassfish and it worked as expected.

Is there a way to solve this (Code or maybe Apache configuration?)

**Note:** I can also add the relevant javascript, if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve this issue in declarative manner, so instead I made a programmatic initialization:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/sliders/